# Query a table to make each row become 3 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (T1) as follows in SQL server:

```
id     subject     student1      student2     student3     score1      score2     score3
1      Maths       Peter         Leo          John         11          12         13
2      Phy         Mary          May          Leo          21          22         23
```

Is it possible to use a query to make the following result:

```
id    subject   name      score
1     Maths     Peter     11
1     Maths     Leo       12
1     Maths     John      13
2     Phy       Mary      21
2     Phy       May       22
2     Phy       Leo       23
```

Answer (score 5):

Although this is an unpivot query, I actually find it easier to do this with explicit logic:

```
select t1.id, t1.subject,
       (case when n.n = 1 then student1
             when n.n = 2 then student2
             when n.n = 3 then student3
        end) as student,
       (case when n.n = 1 then score1
             when n.n = 2 then score2
             when n.n = 3 then score3
        end) as score
from t1 cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3) n;
```

This should have comparable performance to `unpivot`.  And, it should have better performance than three `union all` operations (because that requires scanning the table three times).

Comment: this is neat, but is it actually better than a straight forward union? If it is, I'll upvote you.

Comment: @FrankConry . . . `union` is a bad idea if you want efficiency and don't need to remove duplicates, because a `union` always does duplicate removal.  `Union all` gets around that problem, but typically it would scan the database once or each subquery.  This would typically scan the larger table once, looping through the values in `n`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the table is called classes, you can union it to itself:

```
(SELECT student1 as student, subject from Classes)
UNION
(SELECT student2 as student, subject from Classes)
UNION
(SELECT student3 as student, subject from Classes)
```